# The resource cannot be found in URL routing 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I am using URL routing 4.0 in my project.
It gives me The resource cannot be found, when I am using all same methods in separate test project that works fine, but not with my actual project.

```
public static void SetUpRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        // Add StopRoutingHandler for .axd and .asmx requests
        routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.Ignore("{service}.asmx/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapPageRoute("AllAssignment", "questions/", "~/Questions/default.aspx");

        routes.MapPageRoute("AllAssignmentQuestions", "questions/AllQuestionAssignment/{pageno}",
                            "~/Questions/assignments.aspx", true, new RouteValueDictionary {{"pageno", null}},
                            new RouteValueDictionary {{"pageno", @"^[0-9]*$"}});}
```

I am calling above method on application start in global.aspx
below are the methods for generating link.

```
    private static string GetEntityURL(string routeName, RouteValueDictionary parameters)
    {
        VirtualPathData entity = null;
        entity = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, routeName, parameters);
        if (entity != null) return string.Format("{0}", entity.VirtualPath);
        return null;
    }

  public static string GetAllAssignmentQuestionsURL()
    {

        RouteValueDictionary parameters = new RouteValueDictionary();
        return GetEntityURL("AllAssignmentQuestions", parameters);
    }
```

can any one help me to find out where I am doing mistake.
OR how can I debug all the process.

Comment: You have to post some code at least to get help...

Comment: okay, but my same code is working when I am using the in test project.

Comment: What should i say - i don't have my crystal ball at my fingertips

Comment: just edit your question and add your code which others can find where is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solutions, this happen with me because my application name have the **.**, 
I am using the website and the name of the website is **xyz.web**, when I have convert **xyz.web** to **xyz** it works for me.